# Изменение css в jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Не происходит изменение css свойств у элементов при изменении размера окна. Собственно код на js. Если в функцию поставить `alert('произошло изменение')`, то работает.

```js
$(window).on('resize', formCss());

function formCss() {
  if($(window).width() > 839) { 
    $('#otdel-kachestva .mdc-layout-grid').css('display', 'grid').css('grid-column-gap', '50px');
    $('#otdel-kachestva .name-client').parent().css('grid-column-end', 'span 6');
    $('#otdel-kachestva .number-house').parent().css('grid-column-end', 'span 6');
  } 
  if (($(window).width() > 479) && ($(window).width() < 840)) {
    $('#otdel-kachestva .mdc-layout-grid').css('display', 'grid').css('grid-column-gap', '50px');
    $('#otdel-kachestva .name-client').parent().css('grid-column-end', 'span 8');
    $('#otdel-kachestva .number-house').parent().css('grid-column-end', 'span 8');
  } 
  if($(window).width() < 479) {
    $('#otdel-kachestva .mdc-layout-grid').css('display', 'grid').css('grid-column-gap', '50px');
    $('#otdel-kachestva .name-client').parent().css('grid-column-end', 'span 4');
    $('#otdel-kachestva .number-house').parent().css('grid-column-end', 'span 4');
  }
}
```

`

Comment: Проверьте консоль на наличие ошибок. Убедитесь, что правильно обращаетесь к элементам DOM. Для этих целей лучше используйте CSS медиа-запросы, например: `@media (min-width: 839px){#otdel-kachestva .mdc-layout-grid{display: grid;}}`

Comment: вы функцию выполняете, уберите `()` при назначении обработчика

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как бы начну с того, что прежде чем вызвать функцию `formCss` ее нужно объявить, а потом вызывать.

> Функция (как и всякий объект) должна быть объявлена (определена,
>   `define`) перед её использованием.

Ну и внутри во время вызова функции `$(window).on('resize', formCss);` круглые скобки не нужны. А так - работает вроде все.

```js
function formCss() {
  console.log('formCss');
  if ($(window).width() > 839) {
    $('#otdel-kachestva .mdc-layout-grid').css('display', 'grid').css('grid-column-gap', '50px');
    $('#otdel-kachestva .name-client').parent().css('grid-column-end', 'span 6');
    $('#otdel-kachestva .number-house').parent().css('grid-column-end', 'span 6');
  }
  if (($(window).width() > 479) && ($(window).width() < 840)) {
    $('#otdel-kachestva .mdc-layout-grid').css('display', 'grid').css('grid-column-gap', '50px');
    $('#otdel-kachestva .name-client').parent().css('grid-column-end', 'span 8');
    $('#otdel-kachestva .number-house').parent().css('grid-column-end', 'span 8');
  }
  if ($(window).width() < 479) {
    $('#otdel-kachestva .mdc-layout-grid').css('display', 'grid').css('grid-column-gap', '50px');
    $('#otdel-kachestva .name-client').parent().css('grid-column-end', 'span 4');
    $('#otdel-kachestva .number-house').parent().css('grid-column-end', 'span 4');
  }
}

$(window).on('resize', formCss);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Будет полезно:

- [Объявление функций](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#definition)
- [Вызов функций](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#call)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).on('resize', formCss);

function formCss() {
  if($(window).width() > 839) { 
    $('#otdel-kachestva .mdc-layout-grid').css('display', 'grid').css('grid-column-gap', '50px');
    $('#otdel-kachestva .name-client').parent().css('grid-column-end', 'span 6');
    $('#otdel-kachestva .number-house').parent().css('grid-column-end', 'span 6');
  } 
  if (($(window).width() > 479) && ($(window).width() < 840)) {
    $('#otdel-kachestva .mdc-layout-grid').css('display', 'grid').css('grid-column-gap', '50px');
    $('#otdel-kachestva .name-client').parent().css('grid-column-end', 'span 8');
    $('#otdel-kachestva .number-house').parent().css('grid-column-end', 'span 8');
  } 
  if($(window).width() < 479) {
    $('#otdel-kachestva .mdc-layout-grid').css('display', 'grid').css('grid-column-gap', '50px');
    $('#otdel-kachestva .name-client').parent().css('grid-column-end', 'span 4');
    $('#otdel-kachestva .number-house').parent().css('grid-column-end', 'span 4');
  }
}
```

Помогло!